# In AGAL, when using the 'kil' opcode, does the DepthTest skip that pixel?

Tags: flash, gpu, fragment-shader, stage3d, depth-testing

Let's say I was building a game, and had some tilemaps to create the world in several layers.
The view would be orthographic, basically just a top-down view of the world.

I'm thinking of using Depth-Test to compare which sprites gets drawn from top to bottom (layer-wise). (**Note: I'm aware this may not be the best approach to this problem, but humor me...**)

If I have some character sprites with fully transparent edges (either a keyed-color or zero alpha around the sprite), can I use the '**kil**' opcode in the fragment-shader when that's encountered to make sure the Quad doesn't present a "hole" in the transparent parts of the sprite? (at least that's what I'm assuming would happen).

I guess a more simple question to this is.... does 'kil' ignore that pixel and simply leaves whatever pixel color was there before / in the last **drawTriangles**() call?

Answer (score 0):

`kil` completely discards the fragment, so that means no color, stencil or depth writes.